# Bootstrap container being overshadowed by a div below

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/alowsarwar/0pz3j8f2

Need to get the container its vertical scrolling and never be shadowed the div below. What changes do I need to make. Container contains dynamic forms it can increase to infinite height and the below div should always never overshadow the container. The below div is always fixed to bottom.
I am attaching the concerned jsfiddle link as well.

## css

```
container{
  background-color :red;
}
```

## html

```
<container>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a>
  fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>  fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>
    fffffffffff
  <br>
  fffffffff
  <br>
  ffffffffff
  <br>

</container>

<div class="panel navbar-fixed-bottom"
         style="padding-bottom:0px; min-height:0px">
  bottomaaaaaaaa stuff
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify your question more? Do you need the bottom div to be fixed? or do you want the top container to have a specific height?

Comment: I need the bottom container to be fixed always. And the top container is dynamic in height based on a dropdown. So top container should have a vertical scroll so that we can view the entire top container no matter what is its dynamic height. Currently I can not see some tail part of container becuase it is overlapped by the below div. hope problem is clear now..

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-bottom` to the `html` element, so that the last element will be pushed upwards. This makes sure that the fixed element will not overlap the last element.

```
html{
  margin-bottom: 25px; //adjust accordingly
}
```

```css
html {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
}

.panel.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> fffffffffffddd
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel navbar-fixed-bottom" style="padding-bottom:0px; min-height:0px">
  bottomaaaaaaaa stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this one worked .  body{
   margin-bottom: 100px;
 }

Comment: If an answer worked for you,you should accept it so that other users looking at your questions will already know what worked for the OP

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-bottom: 50px` to your container. So that your content will not hide behind fixed footer. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
    Button
  </a> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br> fffffffffff
    <br> fffffffff
    <br> ffffffffff
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel navbar-fixed-bottom" style="padding-bottom:0px; min-height:0px">
  bottomaaaaaaaa stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, your CDN worked. Can I use this so that I can also set-up my snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But if you see the updated jsfiddle. The padding bottom is static here , it can not increase dynamically. In the latest jsfiddle you see that the container still overshadowed by div.. https://jsfiddle.net/alowsarwar/0pz3j8f2/

Comment: Sweller sure.. I have done some update as well see https://jsfiddle.net/alowsarwar/0pz3j8f2/

Comment: @alowsarwar what do you mean by overshadowed?

Comment: @Swellar yes, the cdn is from bootstrap only.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo If you see the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/alowsarwar/0pz3j8f2/ you can see that the last few line of container are not visible. they are overlapped by the div below

Comment: @Swellar becuase the  padding-bottom: 100px; is a static value this will not serve if the container height grows more and more. So if we can have a vertical scroll for container only, then no matter how long the container grows we can still see all the content in the container by scrolling. And the div below would not disturb us in viewing the container.

Comment: @alowsarwar what am saying is set `padding-bottom` to your `container` with you sticky footer's height. So it will be show hidden content as shown in my snippet even you bind more data on `container`